# PHP: detect if valid string by matching open and closing tag

Tags: php, regex

I got this question for an interview recently and am completely embarrassed that I couldn't figure it out. The task was to find an algorithm to see if a string is valid by it's matching open and closing tag. So:

```
"{This is [an example (of a) valid] string}"
```

{[()]} check is what we are looking for. Any help? I can only come up with the basic string matching in a foreach loop. If $letter == '{', and etc. Would we be using regex here?

Comment: Can these brackets be escaped also like `\}` and what about nested brackets?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but they were probably looking for  a [recursive pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)

Comment: If it was for an interview, I highly doubt they would expect a regex. I would think they want you to write a small parser.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't read the question carefully.  I thought you meant that they were specifically looking for a regex solution.  If not, that's probably not what they were expecting.  As @HamZa said, they were probably looking for a simple parser of some sort.  For instance, you could loop through the string from beginning to end and count all the opening and closing tags and then make sure the counts match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a stack.

Iterate through the string, and push the opening braces on the stack. When you encounter a closing brace, pop a value from the stack and check if it matches the opening brace. At the end of the string, make sure the stack is empty. You can ignore all other characters in-between.

```
function isProperlyNested($string) {
    $stack = [];

    foreach (str_split($string) as $c) {
        switch($c) {
            case "(":
            case "[":
            case "{":
                array_push($stack, $c);
                break;
            case ")":
                if (array_pop($stack) != "(")
                    return false;
                break;
            case "]":
                if (array_pop($stack) != "[")
                    return false;
                break;
            case "}":
                if (array_pop($stack) != "{")
                    return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    return count($stack) == 0;
}
```

But if what you're after is a regex solution, then, well...

```
^(?<p>(?:[^()\[\]{}]++|\((?&p)\)|\[(?&p)\]|\{(?&p)\})*)$
```

Here you have it :)

Comment: If you use `(?R)` instead of `(?&p)`, `^` and `$` would also be recursed, right?

Comment: @stribizhev Exactly. That's why I couldn't use it here.